# Fullscreen minus z-index anchor not clickable

Tags: css, xhtml

The issue

I'm using jQuery supersized for a full screen background image, which will be a clickable advert. Above the main content in the markup, I'm using a anchor tag, position fixed, z-index of -1, display block, and height/width 100%. All that works perfectly, problem is when the z-index is applied the "clickable-ness" of that anchor tag vanishes.

Anyone got any ideas? I could use 2 anchor tags, positioned absolute of the main content and push them out to each side, however I'm not sure how this effect is usually applied.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there anything covering up the <a>? now that it is behind everything?

Comment: No, as the content is within a 960px wide wrapper. When the z-index is changed, the whole page becomes clickable, seems that when the z-index is changed to -1, the anchor tag vanishes, yet if I type in it, the type is above the background image.

Comment: I'll take a look if you make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net) or provide a live page to look at.

Comment: this is a late addition to the project, give me few mins to get a basic live page sorted out.

Comment: Got ot sorted thanks to Snake Faust, just as I got the live page up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower the z-index, the lower it is in the stacking context.

Putting a -1 on the anchor would, theoretically, place it beneath an element with z-index of 0, and so you may be losing click-ability for that reason.

I can't find a reference to back this up, but I don't think negative values are allowed.

Reference for stacking contexts:
[TimKadlec.com -- Detailed Look at Stacking in CSS](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/)

**update**

Some quick fiddling around revealed z-index of -1 on an anchor:

- *with
  nothing else on the page* -- makes it
  un-clickable in Chrome.
- *with
  just one other element on the page*
  -- made the anchor un-clickable in
  Chrome and Firefox (but not IE8)

... so I would advise against the negative z-index. Bump it up to 0, and put z-index of 1 on siblings and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, it is placing it beneath content with a z-index of 0, that is the plan. Yet the unclickable area spans the full width, not just the width of the content above. W3 says neg values are allowed.

Comment: I see. Can you post some markup and css? Perhaps at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yeah the css/html is pretty simple. 

CSS for the fullscreen anchor tag
`code`
#fullscreen-ad {

width:100%;
height:800px;
display:block;
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:-1;
background:blue;
}
`code`
And the content wrapper 

#site-wrapper {
   background:#fff;
   width:960px;
   margin:36px auto 0 auto;
}

Other than tha in the markup its a pretty simple anchor tag followed by  the div.

Comment: I still think negative z-index is your problem. See update on my answer.

Comment: Fantastic thank you. I just got the live page up, and changed it around using 1 and 2 for the values, with a pos:rel on the wrapper.

http://www.eagleworks.co.uk/fsadvert/

Working as planned, thank you.

Comment: CSS [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) supports negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Even though some of your elements may have invisible backgrounds, you still cannot click through them. You must first decide on the set of elements that will not result in clicking the ad. They must all be sibling elements of your advertisement, or children thereof. Now if you set `background-color:red` on them, that is where the user's clicks will not trigger your ad (this is just to visualize of course). You can now set the z-index of your ad to -1 if necessary.

Afterwards you may need to put `position:relative` on the parent element of all these elements, not positive.

There is also a minor chance the body tag might interfere.

Comment: I believe I understand, but if my content wrapper is only 960px wide, and the anchor tag behind is 100%, I am not clicking through a background?